# New Relic says my app is down and Google Analytics says tracking is not installed

Tags: heroku, dns, google-analytics, newrelic

The site works and loads just fine, but I can't get tracking to work and New Relic thinks my site is down all the time. I must be messing up with my DNS or something somewhere?

My URL Forwarding settings on NameCheap:

```
@   | http://www.mydomain.com | URL Redirect
www | myapp.herokuapp.com.   | CNAME (Alias)
```

My "Domains" settings on Heroku:

```
myapp.herokuapp.com
www.mydomain.com
```

My Google tracking script is just in a separate file and included in my application, it shows up in Chrome inspector as it should.

Any help?

Comment: Is that just a typo on the URL forwarding? - `myapp.herokuapps.com` should be `myapp.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I got New Relic to work. It was looking at example.com rather than www.example.com.

Still no idea why Google Analytics was failing, but I started using segment.io instead and now it's fine.

Comment: I've seen it take a while for analytics to detect the code is there - typically I switch to the 'live' view of the data and hit pages, you'll probably find it was working even though it says it's not detected.